# Deutscher Wortschatz - Definition?

Tags: spelling, vocabulary, duden, rules

**Kurzform:**

Wie ist der deutsche Wortschatz definiert?

**Langform:**

Bis zu der [Rechtschreibreform 1996](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reform_der_deutschen_Rechtschreibung_von_1996) war ja der Duden das Standardwerk zur deutschen Orthographie. Wo und Wie ist seitdem die deutsche Orthographie bzw. der Wortschatz definiert?

Entsprechen die beiden immer noch der Fassung von '96, die weiteren Rechtschreibreformen beachtend, oder gibt es irgendwo weitere Änderungen, bzw. ein Standardwerk?

Comment: -1 denn die Frage ist missverständlich gestellt. (vgl. die Antwort von @Jan) Der Duden hat niemals den Wortschatz definiert. Es ist also nicht klar, worauf Du mit Deiner Langfassung hinaus willst.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Der [Rechtschreibrat](http://www.rechtschreibrat.com) hat diese Funktion übernommen. Das amtliche Regelwerk ist dort in zwei PDF-Dateien herunterzuladen:

- [Regeln](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/regeln2006.pdf)
- [Wörterbuch](http://rechtschreibrat.ids-mannheim.de/download/woerterverzeichnis2006.pdf)

Comment: Der Rechtschreibrat definiert aber nicht den deutschen Wortschatz. Er gibt zwar ein Wörterverzeichnis heraus, aber dessen Zweck ist die Klärung der Schreibung von Wörtern im Einzelfall, nicht das Erfassen oder Abgrenzen des Wortschatzes.

Answer (score 3):

Für die Varietät "österreichisches Deutsch" gibt ist seit 1951 das ÖWB (Österreichisches Wörterbuch), herausgegeben vom österreichischen Ministerium für Unterricht, Kunst und Kultur, das einzige amtlich gültige Wörterbuch. Er ist in Österreich und Italien gültig (in Italien für die deutsche Sprachgruppe in Südtirol).

Die aktuelle Ausgabe des ÖWB ist die 42. Ausgabe vom Juli 2012.

- Österreichischer Bundesverlag: [**Österreichisches Wörterbuch**](http://www.oebv.at/sixcms/list.php?page=titelfamilie&titelfamilie=%D6sterreichisches+W%F6rterbuch)

Seit 1951 ist der Duden in Österreich als Nachschlagewerk ungültig. 1996 ereilte den Duden dieses Schicksal nun auch für die Varietät "deutsches Deutsch".

Comment: *"Ungültig"* kann man zumindest für Deutschland nicht sagen.

Answer (score 2):

Der »deutsche Wortschatz« ist semantisch definiert durch die Definitionen von *deutsch* (»eine von ca. 100 Millionen Menschen vorwiegend in Mitteleuropa gesprochene Sprache, die in Deutschland, Österreich, Liechtenstein und der Schweiz den Status einer (ggf gleichberechtigten) Amtssprache und in angrenzenden Gebieten – vor Allem Belgien und Südtirol – zum Teil den Status einer Regional- oder Minderheitensprache genießt. Die Sprache gehört zur germanischen Gruppe der indogermanischen Sprachfamilie und kennzeichnet sich vor Allem durch die zweite Lautverschiebung, das eher seltenen Affrikat *pf* und in der Schriftsprache durch den Buchstaben *ß* (außer in der Schweiz) aus.«) und *Wortschatz* (laut [Wiktionary](https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/Wortschatz) entweder die »Menge der Wörter einer Sprache« oder »die Wörter, die eine Person kennt«). Diese Definitionen ihrerseits wurden von mehreren Wörterbüchern in dieser oder ähnlicher Form aufgestellt, wobei das Wörterbuch der Gebrüder Grimm in der Regel als das erste gezählt wird.

Aus den Definitionen von *Wortschatz* ergibt nur die zuerst angegebene im Kontext Sinn; es kann sich also nur um die *Menge der Wörter der deutschen Sprache* handeln. Diese lässt sich aber nicht definieren: ständig werden neue Wörter erfunden, manche werden nur sehr kurze Zeit benutzt (einige gar nur ein- oder zweimal); andere erleben einen schnellen Auf- und Niedergang; wieder andere sind seit Anbeginn der Sprache Bestandteil und werden höchstwahrscheinlich erst mit der Sprache untergehen. Zwischen diesem Schwarz und Weiß gibt es abermillionen von Grautönen, was zur Folge hat, dass kein Werk imstande sein wird, jemals *alle* Wörter der deutschen Sprache aufzuzählen. Jedes Wörterbuch, jedes Verzeichnis, ob nun von Amts wegen oder nicht, wird eine Auswahl treffen müssen.

Das Problem ist übrigens nicht auf simple Wörter begrenzt. Gerade im Deutschen sind Komposita – zusammengesetzte Wörter – allgegenwärtig, wobei sie in anderen Sprachen oft schlichtweg schlechter zu erkennen sind. Sobald ein Kompositum genau ein bestimmtes Konzept beschreibt, was sich nicht nur alleine durch die Bestandteile erschließt, sollte es auch als *Wort* gelten – nur ab wann gilt das? *Lautsprecher* dürfte noch ein relativ klares Bespiel sein, aber *Bankkonto?* *Grenzstein?* *Bilderrahmen?* Darüberhinaus sind Komposita im Deutschen nicht auf zwei Bestandteile begrenzt: *Bankkontoüberziehungsgebühr, Grenzsteinversetzungsverbot, Bilderrahmenverkaufsdiplom.* Ich denke, dass kein Wörterbuch und keine Aufstellung alle diese Variationen auflisten kann, obwohl sie qua Definition zum Wortschatz gehören.

Folglich bleibt festzuhalten: Niemand definiert offiziell den Wortschatz. Niemand kann ihn definieren. Er ist da, und es lässt sich höchstens feststellen, ob etwas dazugehört oder nicht.

Answer (score 0):

Niemand definiert den Wortschatz. Wer wollte schon behaupten, eine Liste zu haben, die jedes Wort enthält?